# Usage of SAML attribute AttributeStatement

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

in SAML 2.0 you can use the AttributeStatement element to provide any kind of application specific information.

What I was wondering, is it really good design to pass business related information within a SAML assertion? Shouldn't this data be provided in a e.g. separate web services call?

I just want to ask for best practice in this case or any real world experiences.

Regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a lot on just what information you're conveying.  For instance, on the application I work on, we use attributes to indicate what web site features should be shown to the user being logged on.  That's clearly an appropriate use.  Now, we also allow use of attributes to create a user profile, even though we have a web service that does the same thing (and in fact, the implementation calls the web service behind the scenes).  It's not an ideal context for that sort of thing; there's no endpoint to convey the web service response to, or any errors resulting from the attempt.  But we get a fair amount of resistance from customers, who don't want to have to call a separate web service before they can make an SSO call.  So we've had to compromise.  What we've done is require that if a customer wants to use this particular functionality, that they provide an endpoint (either email address or web page) to receive errors from the web service call.  And if they're concerned about security of the information being conveyed, they can use standard XML encryption.

Comment: Yes, I'd agree. If you only provide a limited set of features and want to avoid the costs of building a separate web services, then it should be fine.